# Storing session variables in PHP loaded from mysqli

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I am trying to store session variables upon a login form, so that I can reference them on further pages.  The echo of $row[level] is successful, but none of the SESSION variables.

```
session_start();
   if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $query = "SELECT firstname, level, username FROM `roster` WHERE username ='$username' and password ='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     //while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     //echo $row[level];
     //header('location:begin.php');}
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
        $_SESSION['level'] = $row[level];
        $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row[firstname];}
}}
```

I had also tried this, which successfully works for storing the username as a session variable but not the level variable.

```
session_start();
   if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $query = "SELECT firstname, level, username FROM `roster` WHERE username ='$username' and password ='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($count == 1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        }else{$fmsg = "Invalid Login Credentials.";
    }
}if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$level = $_SESSION['level'];
header ('location: begin.php');
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The code you have shown us above will emit warnings at runtime. Why did you not heed them / see them?

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes here

```
    $_SESSION['level'] = $row["level"];
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row["firstname"];
```

Be sure about looping and overwriting variable value, otherwise use array.

Comment: True - but assuming these are not defined as constants, php will default to treating them as quoted strings meaning this is unlikely to be the cause of the issue reported.

Comment: @symcbean Correct.  These are not constants.